# array.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to add a new value to a array in Javascript with the following code:

```
$rootScope.shoppingCart = new Array();

$rootScope.addToShoppingCart = function(item){
    var quantity = 1;
    var product = [];

    for(var i=0; i< $rootScope.shoppingCart.length; i++){
        if($rootScope.shoppingCart[i].productNumber.indexOf(item.product.productNumber) > -1){
            quantity = $rootScope.shoppingCart[i].quantity+1;
            $rootScope.shoppingCart[i].quantity = quantity;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(quantity == 1){
        product = {
            name: item.product.brandName + " "+ item.product.productNumber,
            price: item.price,
            image: item.product.image1,
            quantity: quantity,
            productNumber: item.product.productNumber,
            productId: item.product._id
        };
        $rootScope.shoppingCart.push(product);
    }
}
```

But when I want to add a new product to the array via the '`addToShoppingCart`' function I get an `$rootScope.shoppingCart.push is not a function` error. 
I my eyes I do not anything wrong because I want to push an array into an array, but it keeps coming with this error.

Is there anybody who sees what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Code seems fine, maybe you override the shoppingCart somewhere else in the code?

Comment: There's nothing related to the error you got in this code. It just means `$rootScope.shoppingCart` isn't instance of a Array, or may be re-assigned in other part of your code.

Comment: you might be making `$rootScope.shoppingCart` as an object or some other datatype before this function call

Comment: try 
if (!angular.isArray($rootScope.shoppingCart))
    console.log($rootScope.shoppingCart);
befoe
$rootScope.shoppingCart.push(product);

Comment: aha! found it! I have also a function ‘loadcart’ which doing a ‘$rootscope.shoppingCart = response.data’ when I disable that function evertything works fine! I going look into that! thanks!

Comment: @NVO in that case you may wanna use this:
Array.prototype.push.apply($rootscope.shoppingCart, response.data)

Comment: @Franky_frankly yeah! that is the trick! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @NVO No, you should not do that. Rather make sure that `response.data` is an array when you overwrite the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply add the following code to 'loadcart' function

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($rootscope.shoppingCart, response.data)
```